# Sum two columns

Tags: vba, excel, sum

In columns `D, E, F, G I` have numbers that I want to work with. I want the sum of columns `F` and `G` to come up in column `H`, and then the product of columns `D` and `E` to come up in column `I`. This is the code I am trying, but nothing is coming up in columns `H` and `I`, where the sum and product should be. My sheet name is `T1`

```
Sub pnltotal()

For n = 2 To lastrow
T1.Cells(n, 8) = T1.Cells(n, 6) + T1.Cells(n, 7)
T1.Cells(n, 9) = T1.Cells(n, 4) * T1.Cells(n, 5)
Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: Please add some more information to your question: I'm missing what programming language you are using (I guess VBA?). Add that as tag as well so people can find your question.

Comment: yes im trying to use excel vba

Comment: why vba?  a formula on the sheet seems like it would work just as well...

Comment: 'next N'? maybe just 'next'?

Comment: fixed it! thank you